# How to create a folder in Google Drive and send a file to this folder without user interaction

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

In my application I need to create a folder in **Google Drive** and send a file to this folder without user interaction.

I use Java Android.

And I didn’t do anything because I didn’t understand anything.

How I can to make this? Please, explain me!

I read [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) and nothing understanding. All posts about Google Drive is very old!

Where should i start?

Comment: Describe your application, show us what you have done, what is expected, provide some resources, from the link I can't understand what is your application based on or what language it is in. Provide more words to your question

Comment: Remember you need the users permission to access their drive account.  So no matter what your going to have to go though the authorization process.

Comment: Where I can to read it? Step by step

Comment: absolutely every example that i saw doesn't work.

Comment: Read this for tutorial in Java: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java It shows you how to perform basic operations (list files on your drive). Try to run this code and understand it. Once you do, it will be easier for you to modify it according to your needs. You can create folders as described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder and upload files into the flder as described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads